# Email validation Javascript+RegEx, but to exclude certain domains

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I have client side email validation script Javascript+RegEx, it works fine, but I want to exclude certain domains while validating, namely all Apple domains since they do not work (emails sent to these addresses are deleted without any notice): @apple.com, @me.com, @icloud.com, @mac.com.

I found appropriate questions here, but still they are not the same I am asking for help.
Please, help to implement this

Can it be done via RegEx modification, or I have to use loop and search substrings (@apple.com, @me.com, @icloud.com, @mac.com) after the main email validation is done?

```js
function verifyMe(){
var msg='';

var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
if(!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) || 
document.getElementById('email').value=='')
{
msg+='- Invalid Email Address: '+email+'\n\n';
document.getElementById('Eemail').style.color='#ffffff';
}
else
document.getElementById('Eemail').style.color='#bbb'
 
if(msg!='')
return false; 
else
{
search_code(); //it's ok go ahead
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you share you attempts and tell us why they didn't work for you?

Comment: I am not sure which approach to use - RegEx mod or loop to search substring? since I want to exclude an array of domains, not a single domain. I am lost with RegEx

Comment: Maybe parse using [a proper email address parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/email-addresses) instead of trying to use regular expressions.  Getting a regex right is going to be hard.  For example, `FOO@APPLE.COM` is equivalent to `FOO@apple.com` since hostnames are case-insensitive, and `FOO@apple.com.` is also valid but just says that `apple.com` should not be resolved using a suffix search-list.

Comment: Those two subtleties are just things I noticed before getting into what can appear before the `@`, and whether you're breaking on the right `@`.

Comment: yes, case-sensitivity is an issue in case of RegEx, so better to use array check, by lowercasing input

Answer (score 3):

Both approaches would work.

For the regex one, just insert the following part after the `@` in the regex (negative lookahead):

```
(?!(?:apple|me|icloud|mac)\.com$)
```

But a better regex overall would be:

```
^\w+[-\.\w]*@(?!(?:apple|me|icloud|mac)\.com$)\w+[-\.\w]*?\.\w{2,4}$
```

For the other approach, the following should work:

```
function isValidMailAddress(email) {
    var match = /^\w+[-\.\w]*@(\w+[-\.\w]*?\.\w{2,4})$/.exec(email);
    if (!match)
        return false;

    var forbiddenDomains = ["apple.com", "me.com", "icloud.com", "mac.com"];
    if (forbiddenDomains.indexOf(match[1].toLowerCase()) >= 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

It's up to you to decide which approach you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `jQuery.inArray()` for checking email with a specific domain name.

```
var email ="abc@xyz.edu.au" 
var str = email.split('@').slice(1);
var allowedDomains = ['xyz.edu.au','abc.edu.au'];

if($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) === -1) {
   alert('email is allowed.');
}
else{
   alert('email not allowed.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated @Lucas answer to match any type of country domain (apple.com, apple.de etc.).

Moreover it should be more robust because its closer to W3C standard: https://emailregex.com/

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@(?!(?:yahoo|gmail|icloud|web|googlemail|aol|zoho|protonmail|outlook|hotmail|gmx|mail)[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]{1,10}$)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$
```