# Laravel: validation for email

Tags: php, regex, laravel, email-validation, laravel-6

I have no idea how to make validation rules for the email field.
I want to accept mail id which are not from server say '@myemail.com, @yahoo.com, @outlook.com' when someone is registering. If this mail address is given it will say your mail id is not valid. what should I do??

please help me, here is my ResigterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mobile_no' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
        'company' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],

    ]);
}
```

[image: controller.php]

[image: config.php]

and I don't have email.php in my config directory.

Comment: please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: you have a mail.php file. http://prntscr.com/q0mvf4

Comment: yes, I have. Please give me an example. One more thing I am using laravel 6

Comment: The mail.php file has nothing to do with validation rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a regex validation on top of that.

```php
$rules = [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'email',
        'max:255',
        'unique:users',
        'regex:/^\w+[-\.\w]*@(?!(?:outlook|myemail|yahoo)\.com$)\w+[-\.\w]*?\.\w{2,4}$/'
    ],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    'mobile_no' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
    'company' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
];
// Add a custom message for regex validation on email field.
$messages = [
    'email.regex' => 'We do not accept mails with this domain.'
];

Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
```

I adapted the regex from [a reply to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388648). The regex should work according to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DpD7lh/1/).

Another option is to make your own validation rule. Refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) for that.

Comment: `\w{2,4}` for TLD is wrong, it accept `1_b` but not `museum`. Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @Toto but it is working and sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: @Toto full disclosure: I do not know how or why this works. I just adapted a regex from another answer that happened to do what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

Comment: This is the exact same as the code that's in the question, except it's formatted differently. The question is about ensuring that emails with certain domains don't pass validation, which this doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use config file seprated for example
config\settings.php

```
<?php
    return [
      'restricted_email_domains'=>[
         'myemail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'outlook.com',
      ],
    ];
```

so, your code would be

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                   if (in_array($value, config('settings.restricted_email_domains')))
                   {
                       $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
                   }
                },
            ],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mobile_no' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
        'company' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],

    ]);
}
```

Reference [using-closures](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-closures)