# Except or exclude authorized email domain

Tags: javascript, regex, proxmox

I have follow this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122885/8345897) and I've change a few adjustments to

`\w+[-.w]*@(?!.+(com|co.kr|net|org))\w[-.\w]*\.+\w{2,4}$`

for match any domain, but except `".com" , ".net" , "co.kr" , ".org"` and contents in email body it's working fine.
[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O78wp.png)
[image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01537.png)

But if there is `".com" , ".net" , ".org" and "co.kr"` before another domain.
Or there is any symbol ( = , + ) it cannot match in this below.
[image_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6cwm.png)

Where do I change to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I've adjust regex completed. Exclude all desired domain `(".com" , ".net" , ".org" and "co.kr")` and another contents in email body.

```
(?i)[\w.+\-]{0,50}@[\w.+\-]{0,50}(?!.+(com|net|org|co.kr)).\w{2,5}\.\w{2,5}
```

The result is perfect. [image: img_complete]

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a match in the last examples because you want to assert that the `.com` `.net` `.co.kr` `.org` is at the end of the string using `$` in the lookahead.

Your last example with the `=` sign in *image_3* does not match as there is no @ sign in:

```
Lorem Ipsum is a long established. abcdxyz=network.0.0.0.clients.server.com.test
```

As there are no spaces in the match that you want, you can change the `.+` to `\S*` to not cross matching spaces.

To match `.com` with the leading dot, you can add that to the pattern before starting the group.

**Note** that starting the match with `\w+` could still get a partial match if there is a non word character preceding it, and using `\w` might limit the range of addresses that you actually want to match.

To prevent that, you can [start the pattern with](https://regex101.com/r/lUDLZX/1) `(?<!\S)` but that has limited support.

```
\w+[-.w]*@(?!\S*\.(?:com|co\.kr|net|org)$)\w[-.\w]*\.\w{2,4}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQpw3B/1).

Comment: @wannarmal You are welcome. If the answer helped solving the question, kindly see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)